# JNA Callback function as a parameter

Tags: java, callback, jna

I am trying to use a native dll from Java using JNA. I am new to both Java and JNA. I am having issues with using callback function as a function parameter to the dll exported method.

Here is how the native function looks,

```
RegisterCallback(UNUM32 hMod, UNUM32 hCLL, CALLBACKFNC EventCallbackFunction)
```

This method basically tells the DLL to use this java method as a callback whenever there are certain events detected by the DLL.

Here is the callback function prototype,

```
EventCallbackFunction(UNUM32 eventType, UNUM32 hMod, UNUM32 hCLL, void *pCTag,   void *pTag)
```

Here is the java side implementation,

```
Library.INSTANCE.RegisterCallback(hMod, hCLL, eventCallbackFunction);
```

The eventCallbackFunction looks like this,

```
public interface EventCallbackInterface extends Callback {

public void callback(int eventType, int hMod,  int hCll, Pointer clltag, Pointer apiTag);
```

}

```
    public class Bridge{
public static EventCallbackInterface eventCallbackFunction = new EventCallbackInterface(){

    public void callback(int eventType, int hMod,  int hCll, Pointer clltag, Pointer apiTag) { System.out.println("Into the callback function: ");}
```

}
}

I do not see any crash but it simply does not work eventhough the DLL recognizes the correct events. Could anybody please help me in this regard ?
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Make sure that you use StdCallCallback if your callback API uses the stdcall calling convention.  Also make sure you keep a reference to your callback object; if it is GC'd then the native code will skip over the non-existent callback.